# Https, Php secure login page?

Tags: php, authentication, https, security

I am new to php, I can do a simple login page, e.g create form, submit form, process and authenticate in a php page and so on.

I read somewhere on the internet, and saw some big companies like banks, google and yahoo, their login form is in "https" not "http". So I try google what is "https" thing. Well, I could not say I fully understand what that thing is, but I think I know the concept, i.e. create a more secure login page.

I believe php could do it (cause I saw wordpress using https, and wp is using php). Is there any tutorial or can you guys give a sample code on how to do a secure login https page with php? Not necessary full code ( cuz I dun want to trouble you guys ), but if can give a full code, would me most appreciated :)

Comment: This url should also help: http://techbasedmarketing.com/business-blogging/how-to-get-https-on-your-domain/902/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Stackoverflow is so cool, just post this questions few minutes ago, and I received so many responses.. Better than those old style forums lol...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to buy a SSL certificate from a company like [Verizon](http://mediumbusiness.verizon.com/products/security/ssl.aspx) or [InstantSSL](http://www.instantssl.com/).  Then, you will need a web host who has Open SSL or another software for processing SSL certifcates installed.

When you purchase a certificate from Verizon/Instant SSL, they will give you some encrypted code using which you could configure your Open SSL software, and then having https:// urls will work.

This isn't something you can do using plain php.

Comment: Thanks. I think I know what to do know.

Comment: You're welcome :). If you have any other questions feel free to comment here and i'll answer.

Comment: Okay. Is there anything I need to pay attention when I write the php code after purchasing the certificate? And should I purchase this certificate for my website? Can 1 certificate use for many pages? E.g, login, update profile, payment etc.. Um, did I asked too many questions? :blush:

Comment: Yea, your https will work for all pages under your domain name, but if you make a different website under another domain you'll need another ssl certificate. I don't think you need to pay attention to anything in particular in your php code.

Comment: There is some PHP work to do: If you have a security certificate your site is still accessible in the normal, non-secure HTTP fashion. Your PHP should check (using `$_SERVER`), whether a page is being accessed by HTTP or HTTPS. If the page should be secure, and it isn't, issue a redirect to the HTTPS version.